# Hiding bar in react native

Tags: react-native

Can anyone help to hide Bottom tab in react native navigation and show tab in stack navigator?

```
<>      
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            headerShown:false,
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
          component={PromotionContent}
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Cart"
          component={CartScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown:false,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="shopping-cart" color={color} size={size} />
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </>
```

I need to hide the bottom tab in Cartscreen.And also in some stack navigator screens,I need to see the bottom bar.I have tried {{tabBarVisible:false}} also but I think it does not exist in V6

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you don't want the tab bar, you just want the functionality of adding different screens to the stack?

If this is the case you don't need a tab navigator component like in your example.

All you will need is a stack navigator with all your screen names defined.

You can have custom components with the navigation feature as long as you have a clickable function to push a screen to the stack navigator using the **navigation.push('screenName')** function and you can remove/pop the last screen from the stack using the **navigation.goBack()** function.

```
<Button
    title="Go to Details... again"
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
  />
```